# Jersey API throwing String Index Out Of Bound Exception

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, tomcat8

I have a web app running on Tomcat 8.0. Using Spring for DI, and Jersey for Rest APIs. While I was working on Eclipse, it was running all fine. Then I deployed it on a Ubuntu machine using the URL:

`http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/app&war=file:/home/user/Downloads/app-name-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`

Now when I hit the APIs, along with the root url, `http://localhost:8080/app`, it is throwing the following error:

```
    16-Jun-2015 16:08:10.026 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-45] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEncodedPath(ContainerRequest.java:377)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getPath(ContainerRequest.java:370)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1463)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone please suggest what is happening here?

Comment: It seems the parameters you are passing while calling service on Ubuntu are wrong... what I can see is it is trying to read parameter value from URl and the value passed is not of correct length

Comment: I have the same issue. I am stumped